# VPN connection between EC2 instance and router from another subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pptp, site-to-site-vpn

We have a problem wile connecting to EC2 instance with Wi-Fi router. I had connected my office router to the EC2 instance via PPTP protocol. Everything is fine and my router's WAN interface got IP address **192.168.90.9** from Windows 2008R2 static pool which I set in RRAS configuration. I can reach all Server's resources from my clinet's workstations (my private home network has **192.168.1.0** network), but not vice versa. So I added static route on the server side `route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.90.9`. But I can't still reach any client in office network (e.g. **192.168.1.33**). If I connect to EC2 instance directly (not via my router's PPTP) then I'm getting e.g. **192.168.90.6** from Windows 2008R2 static pool and I can reach recources in both directions. Please help me to set an appropriate configuration to reach all resources in boith directions. Please note I had disabled NAT on the router.

Comment: The first thing you should fix is to not use PPTP.

Comment: Can you clarify why I don't need to use PPTP? On my router it's possible to connect to the VPN server via ipsec or via pptp.

Comment: Because it is quite insecure. You should be using IPSec instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you help me just establish working connection with PPTP? So I'll be able to reach reverse access to both networks. I mean routes on Windows Server side.

Comment: No, I will not provide assistance implementing an insecure protocol.

Comment: I have just changed PPTP to IPsec with Preshared key authorization. It's working for me but I have the same issue with routing. I can see server's network, but server can't see client's network. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can somebody help me?